# Plot with confidence intervals

Tags: r, graphics, plot, bioconductor, confidence-interval

I am ploting the Gviz Manual example:

```
library(Gviz)
data(twoGroups)

dTrack <- DataTrack(twoGroups, name = "uniform")

plotTracks(dTrack, groups = rep(c("control", "treated"),
each = 3), type = c("a", "p", "confint"))
```

The above code is supposed to plot a figure as in page 21 of the Manual (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Gviz/inst/doc/Gviz.pdf):

[image]

However, what I am getting is a plot lacking the shaded area, which gives the confidence interval, from each group ('control' and 'case'):
[image]

The "confint" type can´t be used at DataTrack function anymore?

Thank you very much!

UPDATE to @SabDeM comment: The version of R and/or Gviz package could be the cause. Please check your version:

R

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "1.1"

$year
[1] "2014"

$month
[1] "07"

$day
[1] "10"

$`svn rev`
[1] "66115"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)"

$nickname
[1] "Sock it to Me"
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] stats4    parallel  grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[10] base     

other attached packages:
[1] installr_0.16.0      BiocInstaller_1.16.5 data.table_1.9.4     Gviz_1.10.11        
[5] GenomicRanges_1.18.4 GenomeInfoDb_1.2.5   IRanges_2.0.1        S4Vectors_0.4.0     
[9] BiocGenerics_0.12.1
```

Comment: Your code works well for me, it produces the first plot with shaded areas.

Comment: @SabDeM please check my update!

Comment: You're using older versions of R and Gviz. Any reason not to update them? It works fine for me with R 3.2.1 and Gviz 1.12.1.

Comment: The version was the issue! Thank you